# How to make a duplicate with the same animation in a different location?

Tags: edit-mode, keyframes

I have made a model and have animated it to run in circles (Using LocRot to do this). I would like to duplicate the model and have multiple running in circles but they are all stuck to the same location. I want to change the location of the x or y axis for all keyframes of the duplicated model. How could this be done? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by first parenting the animated object to an Empty. It's best to do this while they are both free of transforms (X:0,Y:0,Z:0). Then when you make a duplicate, duplicate the Empty together with the animated object. Since the object's LocRotScale will be relative to the Empty instead of the World, everything will behave as you described.

Comment: Omg thats an amazing solution!! I just tried it and it works really well, thank you so much!!

Comment: @Elliott Good! Glad to hear it solved your problem. :-)